# set a person / user as target audience for a custom web part in sharepoint 2010

Tags: web-part, audience-targeting

is there any way by which i can add a specific user or group as target audience of my custom web part programatically ??

i am using

```
                 SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
                 SPLimitedWebPartManager wpm=                                              web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SitePages/UserHomePage.aspx?", PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                AudienceManager am = new AudienceManager(ServerContext.Current);

                wpm.WebParts[1].AuthorizationFilter
                = string.Format("{0};;;;", am.Audiences[1].AudienceID);


                wpm.SaveChanges(wpm.WebParts[1]);
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false ;
```

for setting complied audience to my web part. but my requirement is to add 2-3 specific users or their group as target audience 
** here we can not compile audience for these user.. **

Comment: on a side node AllowUnsafeUpdates should **always** be used inside a try/finally construct, so that if your code breaks the security feature is turned back on

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own People Picker Webpart to the ToolParts collection of your webpart  (see [this post](http://fahadzia.com/blog/2009/08/peopleeditorpeoplepicker-control-as-web-part-property/) for an example).